# How to reduce delay while appending rows in table with javascript loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create rows based on input box blur event. so I have tried the for loop with jquery to append the rows in a table but it will take more time or some time page not respond when loop value reach more than 10000.

```
$("#place_count").blur(function () {
    var row_count = 1;
    if ($(this).val() > 1) {
        row_count = parseInt($(this).val());
    }
    var intial_count = $('#route_places_table tr').length;

    for (var i = (intial_count + 1); i <= row_count; i++) {
        $('#route_places_table tbody').append('<tr><td>' + i + '</td><td> 
            < input type = "text" class= "place_input" name = "places[]" ></td >
            <td>
                <span class="add_row_below row_icons">
                    <i class="fa fa- plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </span> <span class="move_row_up row_icons">
                    <i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i> </span>
                <span class="move_row_down row_icons">
                    <i class="fa fa-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </span><span class="close_row row_icons">
                    <i class="fa fa-window-close" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
            </td></tr >'
        );
    }
});
```

so how to reduce the delay time? or if any problem with my code please help me to improve the code.

Comment: Drop jQuery and use native table methods instead.

Comment: @Teemu what's a native table method?

Comment: you mean javascript.

Comment: @madalinivascu This: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement

Comment: Every append makes changes to the DOM and you do not cache `$('#route_places_table tbody')` so it is fetched each time. You should read up on paging or infinite scrolling

Comment: Why add only a few, say 10 or more, row according to your table height and when there is a scroll event remove previous rows and append new rows?

Comment: Can you explain append the rows in native methods for table @Teemu

Comment: It's pretty simple, first create a row, then create the cells (and their contents) and insert them to the row, then insert the row to the table. You can find examples by following links in the MDN article I've linked above. An easy way is to do all this in a nested loop, like `for(r,rows.length) { createRow; for(cell;cells.length){createCell;row.insertCell} table.insertRow;}`.

Comment: Some other points for a fast table creation. 1) Never retrieve anything from the DOM during the creation process, it causes the DOM to be _re-calculated_, and that will take a lot of time. 2) Avoid complex HTML structures and inline styling inside the cells, rather add the data directy to the TD elements. 3) Avoid adding classes (or any other attributes) to the cells to create columns or recognize cells, use CSS `:nth-child()` rules instead. 4) Don't attach events to cells or rows, delegate events to the table body, and recognize an individual cell/row using `cellIndex/rowIndex` properties.

Comment: ok thank you @Teemu and all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to append only once after the loop has ended, but i strongly suggest to limit the number of rows you append to the page, you don't usually need that many, many dom nodes make the page slow, i suggest you use some king of pagination

```
var html ='';
for(var i=(intial_count+1);i<=row_count;i++){
    html+= '<tr><td>'+i+'</td><td> 
            <input type="text" class="place_input" name="places[]"></td> 
            <td>
             <span class="add_row_below row_icons">
                 <i class="fa fa- plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
             </span> <span class="move_row_up row_icons">
               <i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i> </span>
             <span class="move_row_down row_icons">
              <i class="fa fa-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
             </span><span class="close_row row_icons">
              <i class="fa fa-window-close" aria-hidden="true"></i></span> 
              </td></tr>';     
}
$('#route_places_table tbody').append(html);
```

Comment: We thought of the same thing!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of appending each row one by one, append the whole template at once. This way the time should get reduced.

```
var rows = [];
for (var i = (intial_count + 1); i <= row_count; i++) {
    rows.push('<tr><td>'+i+'</td><td> 
        <input type="text" class="place_input" name="places[]"></td> 
        <td>
         <span class="add_row_below row_icons">
             <i class="fa fa- plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
         </span> <span class="move_row_up row_icons">
           <i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i> </span>
         <span class="move_row_down row_icons">
          <i class="fa fa-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
         </span><span class="close_row row_icons">
          <i class="fa fa-window-close" aria-hidden="true"></i></span> 
          </td></tr>');     
}

$('#route_places_table tbody').append(rows.join(''));
```